# Is it possible to prove that the polynomial $x^4 - 2x^3 + 16$ doesn't have a real zero by writing it as a sum of squares?

Tags: calculus, polynomials

To be able to apply the argument principle to a certain problem, I have to prove that the polynomial $x^4-2x^3+16$ doesn't have a real zero. I think that I can do this by a non-satisfactory, derivative technique:

The value of the polynomial seems to go to plus infinity as x approaches plus or minus infinity. Therefore there must be a globally minimal value at a critical point. Critical points are 0 and 3/2, where the value is positive. Therefore the polynomial can't have a real zero.

A more satisfactory proof would be writing the polynomial as a sum of squares, but that seems difficult. I've tried to get rid of the disturbing $-2x^3$ term by writing the polynomial as $(x^2-x)^2 - x^2 + 16$, but then an equally disturbing $-x^2$ term poppes up. What to do?

Comment: What's wrong with the derivative proof? Seems perfectly fine to me.

Comment: I vaguely recall that someone (E. Artin?) proved a theorem that all-positive-valued real polynomials are sums of squares of polynomials, but I have no idea about either the correctness of that claim or a reference... :)

Comment: Maybe my derivative proof is correct, but I think that it's more elegant to prove something like that with elementary school methods, not even using the concept of derivative.

Comment: With regard to @paulgarrett's comment, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_seventeenth_problem is a good starting reference.  Note that it depends on the number of variables and the degree whether there's a positive result, but that it's true for single-variable real polynomials.

Comment: @BrianMoehring For one variable polynomials the conclusion follows immediately  from the fundamental theorem of algebra.

Comment: I deserve many downvotes for writing a  pointless answer to show that the equation has no real root . Thanks for voting .

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc I don't see the "immediately from the fundamental theorem of algebra" argument, but it definitely follows easily from the theorem that irreducibles in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ have degree $1$ or $2$.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Any real root $r$ has even degree. If $s=a+ib,$ $b\neq 0,$ is a  root then $\overline{s}=a-ib$ is a root as well, with the same multiplicity. Hence the polynomial is represented by the product of factors of the form $(x-r)^{2}$ and $(x-s)(x-\overline{s})=(x-a)^2+b^2$ times a real positive coefficient. By multiplying out we get a sum of the squares.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$x^4 - 2x^3 + 16 = (x^2 - x - 1)^2 + (x - 1)^2 + 14$

Comment: Your $14$ is still unbeatable (+)

Comment: I think this is the best example of how to improve the method attempted in the question. We find that $(x^2-x)^2$ produces a troublesome $x^2$ term. But we can change that term to $-x^2$ (which leads quickly to a solution) by subtracting $1$ inside the parentheses.

Answer (score 15):

$$
x^4-2x^3+16=\frac{1}{2}x^2(x-2)^2+\frac{1}{2}(x^2-2)^2+14
$$

Comment: Wow, great! How did you find that? Just by intuition and imagination, or are there some steps which lead to the desired destination?

Answer (score 5):

There are several ways to find the sum of squares. Here is one using AM-GM.

By AM-GM, we hope to find constant $k$ such that
$$x^4 + k = \frac{x^4}{3} + \frac{x^4}{3} + \frac{x^4}{3}
+ k \ge 4\sqrt[4]{\frac{x^4}{3} \cdot \frac{x^4}{3} \cdot \frac{x^4}{3}
 \cdot k} \ge 2x^3.$$
We find $k = \frac{27}{16}$.
Since the equality case is $x^4/3 = 27/16$ i.e. $x = 3/2$,
we can obtain that
$$x^4 + \frac{27}{16} - 2x^3 = \frac{1}{16}(4x^2 + 4x + 3)(2x - 3)^2.$$

Thus, we have
$$x^4 - 2x^3 + 16 = \frac{1}{16}(4x^2 + 4x + 3)(2x - 3)^2 + \frac{229}{16}.$$

Since $4x^2 + 4x + 1 = (2x + 1)^2$, we have
$$x^4 - 2x^3 + 16 = \frac{1}{16}(2x+1)^2(2x - 3)^2 
+ \frac{1}{8}(2x - 3)^2 + \frac{229}{16}.$$

We are done.

Answer (score 4):

$p(x) = x^4-2x^3+16$ has no real roots iff its [reciprocal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_polynomial) $x^4\, p\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)$ has no real roots. But:

$$
x^4\, p\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \;=\; 16x^4 - 2 x + 1 \;=\; \left(4 x^2 - \frac{1}{2}\right)^2 + \left(2 x - \frac{1}{2}\right)^2 + \frac{1}{2} \;\gt\; 0
$$

---

[ *EDIT* ] The margin is wide enough that it's possible to find other *very* loose bounds, for example:

$$
x^4-2x^3+16 \;\gt\; x^4 - 2 x^3\; \underbrace{-\; 2 x^2}_{\le 0} \; \underbrace{ +\;8}_{\lt 16}\;=\; (x - 2)^2 \,\big((x+1)^2 + 1\big) \;\ge\; 0
$$

Answer (score 4):

Another solution on elementary level.$$x^4-2x^3+16\ge x^4-2|x|^3+16 =:q(x) $$ Then $q(x)\ge 16$ for $|x|\ge 2.$ For $|x|<2$ we get $q(x)\ge -2|x|^3+16>0.$

Answer (score 4):

Another construction :

$$
\begin{align}\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\left(x^2-x-\frac 52\right)^2+\left(2x-\frac 54\right)^2+\frac {131}{16}}\end{align}
$$

---

Since, we have a *cubic* term, we can assume that :

$$
\begin{align}\left(x^2+ax+b\right)^2&+\left(2x+c\right)^2+d\end{align}
$$

Then, the expansion leads to :

$$
\begin{cases}a=-1\\
b=-\dfrac 52\\
c=\dfrac {ab}{2}\\
d=16-c^2\end{cases}
$$

which yields the *sum of squares* .

Comment: This answer should be edit. I will expand it . I will add global minimum and infinitely many different decompositions.

Answer (score 3):

The following seems to work for all quartics (and higher) without real zeros.

---

Observe that if $x^2+ax+b\in\Bbb{R}[x]$ has no real zeros, then
$$
x^2+ax+b=(x-\frac a2)^2+(\frac{\sqrt D}2)^2,
$$
is the sum of two squares. Here $D=a^2-4b$ is the discriminant.

The fundamental theorem of algebra then tells us that a monic quartic with real coefficients but no real zeros is of the form
$$
\begin{aligned}
(x^2+a_1x+b_1)(x^2+a_2x+b_2)&
=[(x-\frac {a_1}2)^2+(\frac{\sqrt D_1}2)^2][(x-\frac {a_2}2)^2+(\frac{\sqrt D_2}2)^2]\\
&=[(x-\frac {a_1}2)(x-\frac {a_2}2)]^2+\frac{D_1}4(x-\frac {a_2}2)^2+
\frac{D_2}4(x-\frac {a_1}2)^2+\frac {D_1D_2}{16}.
\end{aligned}
$$

---

This obviously generalizes to higher degrees.

The real games are about finding an explicit expansion of a given polynomial and/or minimizing the number of terms.

Answer (score 3):

> I have to prove that the polynomial $x^4-2x^3+16$ doesn't have a real zero.

---

We observe $x^3\left(x-2\right)+16=0$ implies that, the any possible real root satisfies $x<2$ . Then, *completing the square* leads to :

$$
\begin{align}x^4-2x^3+16&≥x^4-4x^2+16\\
&=(x^2-2)^2+12\\
&>0\end{align}
$$

Therefore, the original quartic has no any real root .

Answer (score 0):

For $f(x) = x^4 - a x^3 + b$, we have $f'(x) = 4 x^4 - 3 a x^2 = x^2(4 x - 3 a)$. Therefore, for $x<  (>) \frac{3a}{4}$ we have $f'(x) <  (>) 0$ ( at $0$ is $0$).  This means $x = \frac{3a}{4}$ is the unique point of minimum.  Now check that indeed we have a sum of squares

$$f(x) - f(\frac{3a}{4})= \frac{1}{256}(4x - 3 a)^2(16 x^2 + 8 a x + 3 a^2)$$
(the trinomial has discriminant $-128 a^2 \le 0$).

In our case $a=2$, $b=16$ we get

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{16} (2x - 3)^2( 4 x^2 + 4 x +3) + (14 + \frac{5}{16})$$